# Connection to data server fails in IIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, webserver

I have developed a website `asp.net-mvc-4`in `Visual Studio-2010` which gets data from another sql data server that is placed on another location. I used port 443 to make connection and user login to get data. Website works fine in debug mode and it extracts data from the data server but when I upload the website over `windows IIS` it does not make any connection with the data server and hence doest not get data. It fails at the point

```
 if (c.TryLogOn(AccountData.LogInUserName, AccountData.PW))
```

complete method is

```
 try {
            using (Client c = AccountData.c)
            //using (TcpClient c = new TcpClient())                       
            {

                if (c.TryLogOn(AccountData.LogInUserName, AccountData.PW))
                {
                    imc.Search.Base.Query.Query q = new imc.Search.Base.Query.Query();

                    AddAttributeListForFahrzeug(q);

                    AttributeValuesCollection values = c.FindInstances(q);

                    if (tempVehicleType == "all")
                    {
                        foreach (object[] av in values)
                        {
                            Fahrzeug d = NewFahrzeug(av);
                            d.VehicleType = tempVehicleType;
                            returnValue.Add(d);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (object[] av in values)
                        {
                            Fahrzeug d = NewFahrzeug(av);
                            if (d.FzgBeschreibung == tempVehicleType)
                            {
                                d.VehicleType = tempVehicleType;
                                returnValue.Add(d);
                            }
                            //d.VehicleType = tempVehicleType;

                        }
                    }
                    c.LogOff();
                }
            }
        } catch ( Exception ){
        }
```

Connection to the client

```
static public AccountSettings GetAccountData()
    {
        AccountSettings AccountData = new AccountSettings();
        System.Security.SecureString Pw = new System.Security.SecureString();


        string PwWord = "**********";            
        string LogInUserName = "username";
        foreach (char ch in PwWord)
        {
            Pw.AppendChar(ch);
        }

        //AccountData.c = new Client("abc.xyz.zhg.com", 443, true, ConnectionMode.Internet);
        AccountData.c = new Client("abc.xyz.zhg.com", 1199, false, ConnectionMode.Remote);

        AccountData.PW = Pw;
        AccountData.LogInUserName = LogInUserName;

        return (AccountData);

    }
```

Then

```
 AccountSettings AccountData = GetAccountData();
```

Comment: `windows IIS` is on same machine as of your development machine or somewhere else? if it is somewhere else, did you check whether the data server is accessible from that machine or not?

Comment: there is no error message and the failing method `TryLogOn` is not shown. there is not enough information to understand what's going wrong. please add some more detail.

Comment: @user500615 yes it is on the same machine and data server is accesible as I have installed visual studio there in webserver and website works fine in debug mode but when I publish the website on IIS everythign else works fine except the data access.

Comment: @Paolo there is no error message as I mention it does not go into `if (c.TryLogOn`. What else you want to know?

Comment: I forgot to ask you that did you check the event viewer of that machine?

Comment: @user500615 what to look into `event viewer`?

Comment: Any SQL data server connection related error or similar.

Comment: @user500615 I have two SQL databases one on the webserver for user accounts and other sql server from where I am getting data. SQL sever for user accounts that is on local machine is perfectly accessible and there is a log information in event viewer as well that server started but there is no information about remote data server.

Comment: @user500615 please help its an annoying error for me. I have already spent a lot of time on this problem

Comment: can you paste your connection string from web.config?

Comment: Please visit this site, it has the same issue described: http://forums.asp.net/t/1696520.aspx?using+sql+database+in+IIS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55770/discussion-between-wafeeq-and-user500615).